# API de Radio Online

Tags: android

Tenho um arquivo `.m3u` que serve de stream para uma rádio online.
No entanto sou novo nesta área, e queria saber se existe uma maneira de abrir esse *stream* para ouvir a radio online dentro do meu aplicativo.